# JavaScript validation and redirect not working

Tags: javascript, html, forms

This code is not working:

```
 <form name="keeper" action="
                 javascript:if(this.value='')
                 {alert('password empty');};
                 else{location.href = window.document.keeper.page.value + '.php';}" 
  style="margin:2vh;"> 
    <div style="display:inline;"> 
        <input type="text" name="page"> 
        <input type="submit" value="Go"> 

        <noscript>
            <div style="display:inline;color:#ff0000; background-color:#ffff66; 
  font:normal 11px tahoma,sans-serif;"> 
               <br> Javascript is required to access this<br>area. Yours seems to be disabled.
            </div>
        </noscript>
    </div>
 </form>
```

If the text box is empty, when the form gets submitted, I want to `alert("Password empty")`. And if else, I want the script to load `window.document.keeper.page.value + '.php'` in the current page.

Comment: `if(this.value='') should be if(this.value=='')` Also this method is highly uncommon and not recommended.

Comment: @Mouser that true. I tried it. But still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That inline `action` block is highly unreadable and not recommended. There are better ways to do this that adhere more to standards. Please do something like this:

```js
document.querySelector("form[name=keeper]").addEventListener("submit", function(e){
   var input = document.querySelector("input[name=page]");
  //e refers to the event - submit
  if (input.value == '')
  {
      alert("password empty");
  }
  else
  {
     location.href = input.value + '.php';
  }
  e.preventDefault();  //this will cancel the normal submit and execute the code above.
  return false;
})
```

```html
<form name="keeper" style="margin:2vh;">
  <div style="display:inline;">
    <input type="text" name="page">
    <input type="submit" value="Go">

    <noscript>
  
      <div style="display:inline;color:#ff0000; background-color:#ffff66; font:normal 11px tahoma,sans-serif;"> <br>Javascript is required to access this<br>area. Yours seems to be disabled.</div>
  
    </noscript>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you share inline javascript, please?

Comment: You add that script block below the form.

Comment: Hey, the is an error. When I enter anything in the text box and submit, the page loads :https://skools.000webhostapp.com/Admin/[object%20HTMLInputElement].php

Comment: Yup, missed a `.value` in the `else`. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

`if condition` reacquire `==` and also check `this.value==null`

so it will work

```html
<form name="keeper" action="javascript:if(this.value=='' || this.value==null){alert('password empty');}else{location.href = window.document.keeper.page.value + '.php';}" style="margin:2vh;">
  <div style="display:inline;"> <input type="text" name="page"> <input type="submit" value="Go"> <noscript><div style="display:inline;color:#ff0000; background-color:#ffff66; font:normal 11px tahoma,sans-serif;"> <br>Javascript is required to access this<br>area. Yours seems to be disabled.</div></noscript></div>
</form>
```

Comment: This question is half right.  The alert box is showing up, when the box is empty. But it alerts also, when the box is not empty.

Comment: `this.page.value` in the `if` will fix this.